# Module wont create from cmd - Orchard

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using the Orchard tutorials from http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq480A0pgqc

I am attempting to build an orchard module from cmd prompt:
1)Navigate cmd to root folder, 
2)cd Orchard.exe, cd bin, 
3)Orchard.exe, 
4)codegen module BYUtv.CalendarWidget /IncludeInSolurion:true

Which should create the module in my project however cmd displays the error:

[image]

Anyone have any idea why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

opps...Problem was I hadn't 'code generation' enabled from the modules in the dash board.